# for-each syntax cast

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what's going on here?   It looks to me like myObj is being cast to String[] so it can be iterated on in the for loop.  But it was constructed as new String[] -- why does it need to be cast?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Object myObj = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
  for (String s : (String[])myObj) {
      System.out.print(s + ".");
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because it is declared as an `Object`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter that it was created as a `String[]`; you only have an `Object` reference to it.  This is nothing to do with for-each; the following wouldn't compile either:

```
Object myObj = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
System.out.println(myObj.length);  // There is no Object.length
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declared `myObj` as `Object`, you told it to forget that it is anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Why not declaring the array as the actual type? like this:

```
Syting[] myObj = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
```

In that way, the cast is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the apparent type and the actual type. The Object myObj[] statement tells Java that you are declaring an array of Objects. At compile time, that is the only type that Java is interested in. Later when you try to access the elements of the array Java assumes Object and nothing else. The String is called the actual type and is only "known" at runtime. hence the reason for the casting.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the object you are trying to iterate through is checked at the compile time.  And at compile time the only information available is the declared type of the variable.  Compiler can't [reliably, always] figure out that you actually put a String[] there (google "halting problem" to learn why).
The runtime type information is used for polymorphism, type casting, possibly other things I can't think of at the moment.